# navigating range of values without bypassing a starting and ending limit

Tags: java, android

Given a method `private void load_data(long from,long to)` that load then plot some data from a database, two variable `long start_of_today` and `long latest_captured`.

Where `long from` and `long to` are two timestamps in seconds.`start_of_today` and `latest_captured` are also timestamp and are calculated that represent respectively the 00:00 of a day and the timestamp of the latest data in the database.

For example, to load data between 00:00:00 and 02:00:00 Fri May 07 2021, I just call `load_data(1620345600,1620349200)` and I have my data successfully loaded and plotted.

**Based on that method `load_data` and `start_of_today` and `latest_captured` i want to implement two buttons `nexthour` and `prevhour`** which will **permit me to load the data of the next and previous 1 hour** so I tried that:

```
    //start_of_today and latest_captured are calculated and given

    long starting = start_of_today;
    long ending = start_of_today+3600;

    //initially show data between 00:00 and 01:00
    load_data(starting,ending);

    //load data of the next hour
    Button nexthour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    nexthours.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            starting+=3600;
            ending+=3600;
            load_data(starting,ending);
        }
    });

    //load data of the previous hour
    Button prevhour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev);
    prevhours.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            starting-=3600;
            ending-=3600;
            load_data(starting,ending);
        }
    });
```

**and now as you can see the problem with my code is that I will bypass `start_of_today` when clicking `prevhour`...so you know my question, how to avoid that?, What are the changes that I should make to my code so I don't bypass the range of `start_of_today` when pressing the `prevhour` button and `latest_captured` when I press `nexthour`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `if` statement to your click listeners to check whether hour increments/decrements fall out of range:

```
//load data of the next hour
Button nexthour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
nexthour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (ending + 3600 <= latest_captured) {
            starting+=3600;
            ending+=3600;
            load_data(starting,ending);
        }
    }
});

//load data of the previous hour
Button prevhour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev);
prevhour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (starting - 3600 >= start_of_today) {
            starting-=3600;
            ending-=3600;
            load_data(starting,ending);
        }
    }
});
```